# What is "n" for the function "complex(n, inverse)" in npm's FFT?

Tags: node.js, fft

There is a package on npm called `FFT`, and it's main function has no real documentation.

Link to the package:  https://www.npmjs.com/package/fft

Link to the source code where FFT.complex() is defined: https://github.com/jensnockert/fft.js/blob/master/lib/complex.js#L193

The function is

```
var fft = new FFT.complex(n, inverse)
```

When looking through the source code it appears that n is supposed to be a number greater than 0, but that is as far as I've gotten.  Inverse is a boolean indicating whether I'm going to or from phasers.

What is `n` supposed to be?  How do I choose this number greater than 0?

Comment: I'm not familiar with this particular FFT package, but usually n is the transform size (number of elements), and in many cases it needs to be a power of 2, e.g. 1024.

Comment: that's my guess right now too, but it seems strange it wouldn't just pull that number from the array I am inputing

Comment: Could be that it's to allow for transform sizes smaller than the buffer, e.g. If you have 2k samples but just want a transform of the first 1k ?